# Markov's inequality for general random variables

Tags: probability, inequality

Suppose $E(2^{X})=4$. Prove that $P(X\geq3)\leq1/2$.

Using 
Jensen's inequality we know $E(X)\leq2$ but since $X$ is a
general random variable we can't use Markov's inequality to get a
bound for $P(X\geq3).$ Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*HINT 1:* Apply Markov's inequality to the nonnegative random variable $Y = 2^X$, rather than directly to $X$.

*HINT 2:* This obvious statement might come in handy: $X \geqslant 3 \iff 2^X \geqslant 8$.